# BarButton wont appear in navigation menu Objective -C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Story:

I try to create a easy Login app (the username and pw are saved in the `SQlite` db) i have 3 properties two `Labels` and a `BarButton` . the labels are working but the `BarButton`  wont appear i really dont know why .. i tried it several-times but somehow i cant find my error im using `Xcode 4.5.2` /developing on `iPhone SDK 6.0 /Master-Detail Application Layout`, im not using the `Storyboard` im using a `Xib-File`.

```
-(void) keyboardAppearance{
    if(isKeyboardVisible == FALSE){
        isKeyboardVisible = true;
        UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(loginAction)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGo;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: when do you call that method? are you in a viewController at this point?

Comment: this method appear when you start to type something one of the labels . and yes it is in viewController

Comment: @Mingebag: Make sure that the window's rootViewController is a NavigationController.

Comment: @chad how you mene a NavigationController ? as a object im using a simple tableView

Comment: @Mingebag I mean in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method make sure the window's rootViewController is a UINavigationController instance instead of your LoginViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that self.navigationItem is nil, which would mean that your UIViewController is not contained within a UINavigationController. For this to work you need to do something like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];
```

Then present the "navController" instead of "myController".

Hope that helps.